# Can't get back to default UV map

Tags: uv, unity

I made a little volcano model and tried to save the texture to then move it to Unity. It worked fine the first time I unwrapped it but I wanted to try some different unwrapping algorithms. None of them actually worked correctly when brought into unity so I wanted to get back the original UV map, but I don't know how (I tried every single algorithm but nonne of them give the original result). So is there a way to get back the original UV map / tell Unity which algorithm to use to wrap the texture back on the game object?

Edit: I discovered that even the default UV maps don't match with the model when importing into Unity (I tried with another part of the volcano). How do I tell Unity how to unwrap them?

Comment: There's a Reset option on the 'U' unwrap menu in Blender. You should then be able reset then unwrap again using your original method in Blender. No idea about Unity. You'll have to ask that in a Unity forum.

Comment: Reset deletes the UV map, it doesn't make it the default again

Comment: That's why I said use Reset and then select Unwrap again using your original method.